# Online modelling tool for server desing / architecture

Tags: documentation

I am looking for some online (the best is free) tool for designing our servers. We use almost 10 servers now, and it becoming mess, to remember, where, what service is running.

So, I'd like to have some online modeling tool, where I can set up things like:

- server host
- server hw parameters
- server os
- server services with running programs

I am looking for server designing tool like online SQL modeling on http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/?keyword=default (WWW SQL designer)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

It won't help OP but check out [device42](http://www.device42.com). Pretty comprehensive datacenter documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try for start simple DokuWiki (or any other wiki). If you have 10 servers it'll be sufficient.
Also precisely setted Nagios can help with visualisation of network.

Comment: Thanks for help. I decided put server setup into google docs spreadsheet.

Comment: Well, I don't like the idea of sharing my server configuration with Google (or any 2nd or 3rd party)

Answer (score 1):

I've been fairly happy with [RackMonkey](http://flux.org.uk/projects/rackmonkey/). It allows me to define the apps that run on the bare metal, what hosts do what functions, where Staging is for the app, where Development is for the app, etc.

It's also just perl/sqlite3 so it's easy to extend the functionality.